# Conditional column sort

Tags: r, dplyr

I have to sort one column in my df by checking a condition on a string.

Basically, I want to look into `test.name` and based on I want the column to be arranged asc or desc based on the value contained in it.

In the example below, I tried with `paste0` after the pipe, but something is not working.

```
test.name <- "abc"
test.value <- data.frame(a = rnorm(100, 0, 1)
                         , b = rnorm(100, 0, 1))
result <- case_when(test.name == "bcd" ~ "desc"
                    , TRUE ~ "asc")

paste0("arrange(",result,"(b))",sep="")

test.value %>% paste0("arrange(",result,"(b))",sep="")
```

Comment: `arrange` use a different option i.e. `desc` which takes a logical vector

Comment: Would you mind clarifying this, please?

Comment: i.e. the option would be `test.value %>% arrange(b, desc = FALSE)` by default it is FALSE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could use `parse_expr` from `rlang` and evaluate (`!!`)

```
library(dplyr)
test.value %>% 
  arrange(!! rlang::parse_expr(case_when(test.name == 'bcd'~
      'desc(b)', TRUE ~ 'b')))
```

---

Or we can use `across` as well

```
test.value %>%
   arrange(across(b, ~ case_when(test.name == 'bcd' ~ desc(.), TRUE ~.)))
```

Comment: Hi akrun, thank you very much for your time, unfortunately your answer doesn't work... ```Error: incorrect size (1) at position 2, expecting : 100```

Comment: @GNicoletti It is working fine with your example data

Comment: @GNicoletti I updated with the results I got

Comment: I think the reason why your solution is not working is that dplyr doesn't allow the form desc = TRUE / FALSE, but desc(variable) as you can see here https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/arrange.html

Comment: mmmh I am a bit confused... how can your code work on your machine and not working on mine?

Comment: @GNicoletti May be it is the package version.  I updated the code. Can you test it again

Comment: perfect! I'll check if it's my version too old!

Comment: @GNicoletti in the new version, you may use `across` (updated as it is more flexible)

Comment: I guess this across() function is from the tidyverse package, right? I will go and study what it does - thank you very much!

Comment: @GNicoletti it is from `dplyr` alone.  You can just load `library(dplyr)`